# Se debe hacer la suma de los elementos de forma recursiva pero se deben sumar los elementos en base a los extremos

Tags: java

Por ejemplo tengo el arreglo `A=[2,3,5,1,2,2]`
entonces tendría que sumar las posiciones en esta forma `aux=A[0]+A[6]`, `aux=A[1]+A[5]`....
Pero se tiene que tomar en cuanta cuando el numero de elementos es par o impar y tiene que ser de FORMA RECURSIVA. Por el momento esto es lo que llevo de código:

```
public static int decremento2(int aux,int ini, int fin, int A[]){
       if(ini == fin || ini+1==fin){//Cuando ini==fin es cuando estamos en el caso IMPAR y cuando es ini+1==fin es el caso IMPAR
           if(ini==fin){
               aux=aux+A[ini];
           }
           else{
               aux=aux+A[ini]+A[fin];
           }
           decremento2(aux,ini,fin,A);
       }else{
           aux=A[ini]+A[fin];
           decremento2(aux,ini,fin,A);
       }
       return aux;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La logica de tu ejercicio que explicas, no tiene logica.. da lo mismo como sumes el array, el resultado siempre es el mismo... seguro que asi es la definicion de tu ejercicio????

Comment: Y esa funcion recursiva, nunca termina.. nunca devuelve ningun valor.. o entra en un lado del if, o en el otro...

Comment: @gbianchi es por eso que pido ayuda porque no se como solucionar esa situacion

Comment: Bueno.. yo no puedo ayudarte, porque ni siquiera entiendo cual es tu ejercicio. Lo que planteas no tiene sentido ni como ejercicio de la facultad.. podrias explicarme que sentido tiene hacer la suma asi?

Comment: @gbianchi, se puede ver que el sentido de pedir la suma de esa manera es un ejercicio para mejorar la lógica que tiene en la recursividad, por lo que no veo nada de malo en su pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

La recursividad puede ser confusa, por lo cual siempre recomiendo que estudies antes el principio ***LIFO** (Last in First Out)*.

Para tu problema vamos a detenernos a pensar un poco.

1. ¿Qué casos posibles hay?

   - R: Que sea par o  impar
2. ¿Cuántas veces se debe de llamar a la función recursiva?

   - R: **0.5 n** (el resultado se trunca a 0 decimales (7/2 = 3.5 -> 3)), donde n es el número de elementos, esto porque vas a recorrer al arreglo por el inicio y el final al mismo tiempo
3. ¿Hasta cuando debo parar mi función recursiva?

   - R: Hasta que llegue a i == **0.5 n**

**Código**

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumArray(new int[]{2,3,5,1,2,2}, 0, 0));
        System.out.println(sumArray(new int[]{2,3,5,1,2}, 0, 0));
    }
    
    public static int sumArray(int[] vector, int i, int sum) {
        if (i == 0 && vector.length % 2 == 1) {
            sum = vector[vector.length / 2];
        }

        sum += vector[i] + vector[vector.length - i - 1];

        if (++i < vector.length / 2) {
            sum = sumArray(vector, i, sum);
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

**NOTAS:**

Como vemos, se propone para considerar el caso de que el arreglo sea impar en estas líneas:

```java
if (i == 0 && vector.length % 2 == 1) {
    sum = vector[vector.length / 2];
}
```

Si es la primera iteración y el arreglo es impar, la suma directamente es el elemento de la mitad de nuestro arreglo

Se hace un pre-incremento en la llamada recursiva

```java
if (++i < vector.length / 2) {
    sum = sumArray(vector, i, sum);
}
```

Esto para decirle que la siguiente iteración es con `(i + 1)` y ese es el índice que tomaremos como referencia para compararlo si llegamos a **0.5 n**

**Output**

```
15
13
```